# Android: using Facebook sdk with android 2.2

Tags: android, facebook

I have an Android 2.2 project that I need to use the facebook api in it.

after adding the facebook sdk project and adding the the facebook project library to my android 2.2 app libraries, nothing happens and when I go to my app properties->android-> i found that the facebook libary project has a red X mark beside it.

is it a problem caused by different versions ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the answer from here

[In eclipse, unable to reference an android library project in another android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pro)

I had to put the facebook api library project in the same workspace of my app project