# how to use a .so and .jar in a java android projet?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, static-linking

I'm working on a java android project. this project requires to use specific commands.
these commands are all developed in c++/c but I've been given two files (.jar and .so) that are supposed to "turn them into" java, so I can use them in my java android project.

The thing is, what am I supposed to do with these 2 files?? I've read a lot of stuff (mostly about creating the .jar and .so, but I don't care about this step, for I already have the 2 files)

I tried to import the .jar (import external lib), I tried to add the .so via the static loading : 
        //static {
    //          System.loadLibrary("MySoFile");
    //      }
All I get is a stack overflow error or a problem with the DEX file...

Has anybody ever tried to do this??
I don't seem to get the point here...all I want to do is being able to use the commands in the .jar file.... ://

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283040/eclipse-android-project-how-to-reference-library-within-workspace/9283084#9283084) about adding `jar` files. '.so' files can usually just be drag and dropped to the project.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make sure the jar is in your classpath and you can then access the classes within this jar.  A jar is just an archive of classes, you don't need to load the library into memory or something similar.

You may want to read the answer to the question here [How to use classes from .jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files)