# ClassNotFound when using one project inside another in Eclipse

Tags: java

I use eclipse and have Android project that is specifically designed to be used by other projects. It is not a library, it is an Activity, and from other projects I want to extend that Activity.

So, I have my first project that goes like this:

```
public class MyGenericActivity extends Activity {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // (...) and so on
    }
}
```

Now, keeping my first project open I create a new project.

In Eclipse, under *Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects* I add the first project.

Now, after having automatically imported what I need, I can write inside the new project

```
public class MySpecificActivity extends MyGenericActivity {
     // (...) and so on
}
```

Eclipse does not give me any syntax error, but as soon as I run the project I get this:

```
09-02 22:54:00.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 22:54:00.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1003): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{<new project>/<new project>.MySpecificActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <new project>.MySpecificActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/(...).apk]
```

What's happening? Is it a compile problem? A Java problem? I really cannot spot this.
Thank you.

Comment: you class name starts with a capital letter and you extend with a lowercase letter

Comment: Sorry, that is a stupid error that I made writing the message here, I correct it. Obviously they are both upper case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are ok while you are developing. Probably you have problems while deploying your app.

Take a look at: [Eclipse Android project, how to reference library within workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283040/eclipse-android-project-how-to-reference-library-within-workspace)

Comment: Thank you. I missed one of the 5-6 steps :)