# How to include a custom library from GitHub into my Android app?

Tags: android, github, javascript

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol) library off of GitHub for a Segmented Control in Android.

My problem is that I do not know how to include the provided library into my existing project.  I've tried copying the src and res files (of the library and sample) into my project and modifying their package names to match mine, but the files are filled with errors and will not compile.

I am new to Android development, and so I am unsure how to bring these files in to my project so that I can use them and create the desired segmented controllers.

**Note:** I am using the Eclipse IDE from the Android website (ADT v22.6.2).

Comment: As a slightly experienced programmer (about 4 years) I agree that this can be very confusing, and harder than it should be. My advice would be to keep it separated from your own packages as a separate library, for starters. Linux people always assume you know how to install/utilize stuff :p

Comment: Which IDE are you using to develop your application? Is it Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: @michaelcarrano I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there you will want to actually clone the whole repo and import that project as its own project and then reference that project via this method. [Eclipse Android project, how to reference library within workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283040/eclipse-android-project-how-to-reference-library-within-workspace)

Good luck.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  Got the sample to work using the method you suggested.  The problem now is that the library is a separate project within the workspace.  When it comes time to submit my app for people to use, will it automatically know to include the referenced library?

Comment: Yes, it will automatically include the reference library. One simple way to test is to build and run your app using the libraries functionality... If that works, then you did everything correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I see now in the project files that it created a `segmentedcontrol.jar` file within the Android Dependencies folder for the project, so it's done all the work for me!  Thank you again for your solution - very helpful!