# Eclipse[Android] refer several librairies in the same project

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, google-play-services, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm working on an android application and i want my users to login with facebook and google+ button so i have to add google play services-lib and facebook sdk the problem is that i can not refer to more than one library in my project eclipse won't let me any suggestion please ?

Comment: what exact error are you seeing?, provide a screenshot if you can

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283040/eclipse-android-project-how-to-reference-library-within-workspace

Comment: @jucas When i want to refer to facebookSDK everything looks fine but nothings happen in the project when i go back facebbokSDK is marked red

Comment: @Foreever i already checked that link it doesn't work for me ..

Comment: @NihelAlaoui 
1. Import your library projects into eclipse

Comment: @amsiddh can you tell me how please ?

Comment: @NihelAlaoui 1.Import your library projects into eclipse 2. Right click on your actual project > properties > Android > right side at bottom in Library section click on Add and select your library projects and click ok, then click on Apply then Ok. This will set reference to those selected libraries with your actual projects. 3. Clean projects, from Projects > Clean

Comment: @NihelAlaoui File > Import > Android> Existing Android code into workspace > Next > Browse to and select library directory > After selecting it will show in below projects section with checked mark > click on Finish.

Comment: Thank you so much but it doesn't work either..

Answer (score 0):

Click right on the Project after choose Propreties then click ANDROID in the bottom you'll see libraries  click in add and choose libraries that u want I hope that wil help you