# Want to add facebook library in my project

Tags: android, eclipse

I download the Facebook API and import it on my eclipse workspace.Now when i am adding this Facebook library in my project by right clicking on my project then properties>>>Android>>>Add
it shows the Facebook library.When i am select it and click OK,the library cannot be added to my project.I am using eclipse helios and ADT 17.0 with android SDK upto android 4.0.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following links:
[facebook android sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)
and
[facebook android sdk tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Please also check this thread: [In eclipse, unable to reference an android library project in another android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr)