# Adding Facebook Library in Android Project

Tags: android, facebook

I have added Facebook Library into an android project **Project--> Properties-->Android--->Add Library** at the time of adding it shows green mark against lib. but when I again follow the same path it shows red mark against libs. 
>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want to add facebook library in my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979098/want-to-add-facebook-library-in-my-project)

Comment: add in library project. clean and build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that your `project code` and `facebook library` are in `same folder`. 
Sometimes if your library is in another folder it doesn't allow you to import library in your project.