# Unable to import MoPub android sdk

Tags: android, import, mopub

I am trying to import the MoPub sdk into eclipse, but I am getting following error:

`[2012-06-28 13:43:46 - mopub-android-sdk] Unable to resolve target 'android-4'`

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the mopub-android-sdk files in the same parent folder as your project? This seems like the same problem addressed in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr). Have you installed Android 1.6 platform on your sdk?

Comment: I have android 2.2 and 2.3.3 installed but not 1.6, do I need to install 1.6 as well ?

Comment: The `android-4` it's looking for is 1.6. I believe mopub uses that for its minimum api level. You don't have to target it for your app, but it needs to be there for the import to work.