# Importing external android libraries to IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I wasted a day on trying to import external library into IntelliJ. I've done everything that was mentioned [here](http://soledadpenades.com/2011/06/17/android-library-projects-with-intellij-idea/), but I keep on receiving *android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException* when I try to use [quick action library](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction). Please help, I really don't want to use Eclipse.

Comment: Zip and share your non-working IDEA project to save others time when trying to reproduce this configuration issue.

Comment: check what java compiler you are using. i always had issues when i used the default, i have to change it `Javac in-process (Java6+ only)`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the assistance, I've found the solution. It's [here][1]. Now when it converted my answer to a comment, how do I close this question?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr