# Adding ActionBarSherlock to project

Tags: android

I am trying to add actionbarsherlock to my project. This is a huge project most of the code is written. I have imported actionbarsherlock to my workspace, and when I try to add it as a library to my project eclipse "just forgets" that I added the actionbarsherlock.

[image]

When I enter this screen again, the reference to actionbarsherlock project is gone! What is wrong with eclipse? Caveman-tool..

Comment: Are you checking the box "IS Library" ?

Comment: Or check here, it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr

Comment: No, the tutorial that I read didn't do it. So the answer is no.

Comment: i wonder if there is any limit on the number of directory levels you are allowed to go "back up". the path is going back up to /, and then down in to your Users directory. this could be a problem? It would be a good test to try with the actionbarsherlock folder somewhere closer to the project you are trying to add it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the file permissions on the `project.properties` file?

That is where all references to library projects are kept. My guess is that it can't write the changes to the file.

Comment: Yeah. Of course! Team Foundation Server had set this file to read only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your actionBar project ->properties-> Android and check IsLibrary

Comment: Do you mean my sherlockactionbar project or the project that where I want to include actionbarsherlock? In the actionbarsherlock project this option is checked.

Comment: your sherlockactionbar project which you want to use it as a library there u make these changes

Comment: That's a false statement. I have to include the actionbarsherlock the way I do. But eclipse wont remember my settings..