# Android : can't import library in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, libraries

I'm really annoyed by eclipse ! I'm trying to use external project as a library (Sliding menu from J. Feinstein). The import of the library in eclipse is ok, but when I open the properties of my project and add it as a library, It doesn't work.
Eclipse tell me that it's ok, but when I build the project, I have an error telling me that eclipse can't find library.apk.
If I check the properties again, there is a red cross id front of my library.

Here is a little screenshot from the the properties window in eclipse.
http://snag.gy/4jnKk.jpg

Comment: a library, in this case, is a `.jar` file, not an .apk.

Comment: this may solve you problem  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr/5167294#5167294

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this row, and using "Add" connect your library project to current project. 
If you have  .jar file, copy it to libs folder and use "Properties - > Java Build Path - > Add jars".

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself... I was using Egit plugin as CVS and it mess up something ! 
Now I'm using a console to handle git, and I've no problems anymore.. Thanks anyway :)