# Step by Step procedures in using ActionBar Support API on Android 2.1

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android development and Eclipse IDE, currently I'm following the android training when I try to execute the procedures(http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) in adding action bar on android 2.1 I can't successfully reference the appcompat because Eclipse can't find this theme(Theme.AppCompat). I tried numerous solution found on the web but still no success.

I'm using eclipse juno with Android SDK v22 and the latest ADT on windows7. Is there a step by step procedures with screenshots in using appcompat for ActionBar? Screenshots will be a big help for me as newbie.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the support lib from your Android SDK folder. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support?rq=1) post.

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

See below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html