# Android Support Library v7: Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I am trying to build the Android Support Library v7 samples.

For that, I created an sampleproject through Eclipse -> New Android Sample Project and added the android-support-v7-* projects as "Android Project From Existing Code" to Eclipse, and made the sample project reference them.

But I am getting the following errors in `android-support-v7-mediarouter/res/values/styles.xml`:

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'.` (line 18)

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton'.` (line 28)

What can I do to fix these errors and build the sample project?

Comment: I think you should change your target version to 18 in the manifest.

android:targetSdkVersion="18"

Comment: Remember to do a project clean after changing the API level. Api level 14 or 15 or above will do.

Comment: I have target API 18 on all projects (in project.properties), and target SDK 18 in the samepl project. Cleaning all projects helps nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You must make the android-support-v7-mediarouter project "aware" of the android-support-v7-appcompat project as a referenced library.

1. Right click **android-support-v7-mediarouter** project, select **Properties**
2. Select **Android**
3. In the **Library** section at the bottom, click **Add...**.
4. Select **android-support-v7-appcompat** in the dialog.
5. Click **Apply**.
6. Click **OK**.
7. Do a clean build on the **android-support-v7-mediarouter** project.

Comment: That did it, perfect. Wouldn't have thought it would be that simple.

Comment: I recently had this error.  Thanks.  I also had to set to API19

Comment: Please specify which "Add" to click. There is Add JARs, Extrenal JARs, varaible...which one?

Comment: (cleaned-up answer to Eatlon) You're on the wrong screen.        You're on [Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries(tab)]. Instead, go to [Project->Properties->Android]. There's one "Add" there (although you may have to scroll down to see it).