# Fixing Error in styles.xml to generate R.java : No resource found name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Tags: android, xml, android-support-library, r.java-file, android-appcompat

I am new to Android and am trying to run my first program. However, based on my searches across the internet, I think that I can't import `mypackage.R` because `r.java` has not been generated because of errors in my style.xml files. I have searched around trying to figure out how to fix these but I can't find a fix that works. The error in `styles.xml` is

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

![Errors in style.txt][1]

Here is the code I am using:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

UPDATE:
Here is styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

UPDATE 2:
Here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: the problem is in your styles.xml, please add it to your post.

Comment: updated to add styles.xml code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` theme which is a library project. You have to reference this library project to your project.

Now, at first, check that you have installed this library project as follows...

Go **Window**-->**Android SDK Manager** then a window named **Android SDK Manager** will appear as below.

[image]

If the `Android Support Library` is not installed then install it. You can see more information about `Android Support Library` setup from the below Android Developer site.

[Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

After `Android Support Library` setup completion, reference the library to your project from this path...

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

To reference, follow these steps:

1. **File**->**Import** (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "**appcompat**"
2. **Project**-> **properties**->**Android**. In the section library "**Add**" and choose "**appCompat**"

Now, clean and build your project and run it. I think after all of these, your problem will be solved.

Comment: that just created another error- `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Light'.`

Comment: Where do I find the LogCat? (In Eclipse)

Comment: now there is no error for theme.light!
I am not sure what I did, I was just trying to include appcombat in project, then i checked back and there is no error in styles.xml

Comment: however, there are still errors in the `styles.xml`s that are in values-v11 and values-v14

Comment: @ravensgo...see my updated answer...and forget about the previous answer.

Comment: I did what you said and now there is no error in the styles.xml files in values-11 and values-14, but there still is in values. Do you know what mistake I may have made or is there a way to check if I did it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the problem.  I had to delete this line of code from my `main.xml`:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

Under my `values-v11` and `values-14` folders I changed the name of the app to...

```
style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"
```

...and it is currently working.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in your Theme, you have to include `appCompat` into your Project.

- File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat"
- Project-> properties->Android. In the section library
- "Add" and choose "appCompat"

That should work.

Comment: It says select an import source, I tried typing filter text as android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7 and appCombat but nothing came up. What am I supposed to select?

Comment: Oh you have to go your sdk folder and `appcompat` folder located under `extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` ..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you closed the `<resources>` tag properly and add at the bottom of your styles.xml:

```
 </resources>
```

according to your posted code snippet that is not present, but needs to be

Edit: the missing resources tag was just a copy-paste bug in question, so here that was not the reason.

Comment: my bad, I just didn't put four spaces in front of the end tag and it didnt show up in code... it was there in the actual xml doc

Comment: ok then I suggest you just switch to another theme like the mentioned "android:Theme.Light" that should be pretty fine for an HelloWorld app

Comment: uy, then I think it makes sense to take a look at your AndroidManifest.xml, maybe post it as well.

Comment: also the manifest seems ok... maybe try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19886189/2399024