# resource entry app_name is already defined

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)

**errors are Showing like this**

```
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. [2015-08-17 11:26:16 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. [2015-08-17 11:26:16 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. [2015-08-17 11:27:54 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values\styles.xml:21: error: Resource entry app_name is already defined. [2015-08-17 11:27:54 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values\strings.xml:4: Originally defined here. [2015-08-17 11:27:54 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values\styles.xml:30: error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Successfully Posted \ '%1$s\'.\nPost ID:  [2015-08-17 11:27:54 - LoginWithSocial]         %2$s) [2015-08-17 11:27:54 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. [2015-08-17 11:27:54 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. [2015-08-17 11:27:54 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. [2015-08-17 11:27:54 - LoginWithSocial]
D:\workspace\LoginWithSocial\res\values\styles.xml:21: error: Resource entry app_name is already defined.
```

Comment: Update your Support Library...see answer here [Link]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22271850/2829107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your application SDK Version (minimusdk 14 and targetsdk version 22)

Comment: Can you explain please?