# Errors setting up Google Cast Example 'CastHelloText-Android'

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cast

I'm trying to set up the CastHelloText-Android example app from https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android.

I'm on a fresh install of 14.04 x64.  I downloaded the Android SDK from Google yesterday (adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702).

Eclipse is giving me the following errors:

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionProviderClass' in package 'com.example.casthelloworld'   main.xml    /MainActivity/res/menu  line 20 Android AAPT Problem
>
> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.casthelloworld'  main.xml    /MainActivity/res/menu  line 20 Android AAPT Problem

This is main.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

I have the following external JARs included:

- android-support-v7-appcombat.jar
- android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar
- google-play-services.jar

Answer (score 0):

I was adding JARs.  I should have added the android-support and google-play projects to eclipse.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969475/1639019

That describes the process perfectly.