# Cannot build a new Android Applications project on ubuntu with Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to build a project but when create this error display.

```
[2015-04-12 11:38:25 - Em] /xxx/xxxxx/workspace/Em/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBa
```

r'.

I do not have idea what Can be this issue but all source mark acces error to source "R." Like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_echile);-->Error "R."
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a Ubuntu nor Eclipse problem. The error is indicating, that SDK can't find required resource, and it is an AppCompat resource, which means that it included in a support library. You need to add it manually, instruction you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).

If you have already imported it, but it doesn't work, you may try this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969475/4671372).

It seems like, you have chose, when creating Android project, to use Dark Theme. Sometimes happens, that Theme resources not loaded automatically. If it is not critical to you, which theme to use, you can always choose `None` theme, cause it don't need to load additional resource.

Comment: Thanks I had the same problem on Windows but I cannot remeber the solution in that moment, but now I dont forget never.