# developer.android.com training actionbar - correct result?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am currently following the tutorials on http://developer.android.com/training/index.html.
I have completed the first section and continued the second section on the same code.

In the tutorial the goal is to make an ActionBar.
I have chosen to support android 2.1 and above using the v7 appcompat library.
I assume it is installed correctly (and have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support) thread).

My question is, what is my result supposed to look like?
I have created 2 AVD's, one running API 18 and one running API 8 and am testing on my own phone (Xperia Ray running Cyanogenmod 9, which is API 15 I believe)

All 3 devices give different results.

- The AVD running API 18 shows the app with an actionbar in both the main activity and a secondary activity. Pressing the logo in the Actionbar in the second activity returns to the parents activity.
- The Xperia Ray phone (API 15) also shows the actionbar in both activities but does not return to the parent activity after being pressed. I suppose I still need to program that and is not standard in API 15?
- The AVD running API 8 shows an actionbar in the main activity with the name of the app but shows **no actionbar in the second activity**.

This is the code I used, from the tutorial linked above:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { ... }
```

and in the manifest in the < application > tag

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Should this be enough to make an actionbar appear in lower versions of android or is it supposed to not show an actionbar besides the main activity in lower versions?
I'd like to fix this before continuing the tutorial.

If my question needs more clarifications, I'd be happy to provide it. All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the home button: Starting in API 14, you need to call [setHomeEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)) while the button was automatically enabled in earlier APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I did wrong.
Following the tutorial litterally, the second activity will not have an actionBar.

In each of the activities java file, the class must extend ActionbarActivity instead of Activity. (The tutorial only explicitly tells to change the main activity)
--> This makes an action bar appear in every activity.

To make the back or home button appear in all versions, I did it like this:

```
//Make sure we're running on HONEYCOMB or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 7 ) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //for older versions
            //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); //without arrow
        }
```

The first if statement should already be there by default (I commented it out as it was left out some of the code examples in the tutorial. Leave it in!).
getSupportActionBar() needs to be used on older APIs (make sure the appcompat library is included correctly). Using getActionbar() on older APIs causes a Forced Close.
Using setHomeButtonEnabled() works too but is without the < icon in the action bar.

Thank you for the replies. If anyone has other suggestions or tips, they are always welcome. (are both if statements needed?)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with AppCompat, but I recommend ActionBarSherlock appCompact, is very easy to use. Link: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

You can also customize the style with: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

good luck ;)