# Eclipse not picking up Android Support Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm getting this :
[image]

and I'm not sure if the red tick marks in SDK Manager are related :

[image]

I have the files and they appear to be in the correct locations :

[image]

And my SDK location appears correct :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing v7/appcompat as a library project to Eclipse and then add to your project.

Library project is at following path:

```
sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

Also take a look at how to use this recently updated library for supporting ActionBar on older versions.

Comment: I can see the option to add a library to my project but not to add the library to Eclipse. How do you do that ?

Comment: Found it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support