# Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

Possible duplicate of [Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support) but here solution is only for ecllipse, How to solve this error in IntelliJ IDEA ?
Please explain step by step.

Comment: Did you include the appcompat library correctly?

Comment: jar file dependency is not enough because appcompat contains also resources. You should have aar, apklib dependency or include it from Android SDK as project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only included the jar. But jars do not include resources (and therefore not the theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light`). You have to either include the whole lib with its resources (you can find it in your sdk folder in the extras folder) or you include it with gradle like @MichaelBarany already suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the dependency in your `build.gradle`?

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+"
}
```