# Gradle can't resolve AppCompat themes

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I have imported appcompat library through:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

in my {ProjectName}/{ModuleName}/build.gradle. The library shows up in external libraries. Yet, I can't build the app because when I try, there's an error in my styles.xml:

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'
```

This is where I declare a theme to derive from AppCompat theme, like this:

```
  <style name="TextStyleSuperClass" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  </style>
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support

Comment: Thanks for taking interest, but the accepted answer in this link is for Eclipse IDE. The Android Studio + Gradle combination should just import the library with the resources. But somehow, it doesn't see the resources :/. I'm doing it like it says in the doc: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Answer (score 1):

On this site "[Getting ActionBar support library working with Android Studio](http://lstrburnham.wordpress.com/tag/intellij-idea/)" I'v found the following line and added it to the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

From that on Android Studio was able to resolve `Theme.AppCompat`

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip the @style entirely. Use:

android:theme="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

This works with version 25 of the SDK