# R cannot be resolved to a variable - cleaning doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse

I've recently deleted some other projects from my eclipse workspace (permamently) and after that in my current project appeared some errors (R cannot be resolved to a variable).

I tired cleaning and building again project, but this time it doesn't help.

In resources, errors appears only in styles.xml files:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

I'm new in android development and I don't understand what's exactly wrong. Probably something with theme, but I tried to change it to something different - without effects.

Comment: Have you checked out posts like this [appcompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support) question?  Followed all of those suggestions?

Comment: Check the version of android you are building with. The current version you are using doesn't have that theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [`v7-appcompat`](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) library, import it into Eclipse and reference it in those projects which are showing this error. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Here is more detailed instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support