# Theme.AppCompat.Light resource not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

When trying to extend ActionBarActivity I need to use the AppCompat theme (Theme.AppCompat.Light). When I try to add it in the manifest and styles.xml I get

> Error:(31, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light').

Eventhough I have downloaded the support libraries and included this in my build.gradle file ->

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'}
```

Comment: I have the same problems. Using Android Studio 0.8.2 on OSX.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

Answer (score 24):

In Android Studio, I had this same error when using `android:theme='@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light` but when I use `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` inside the AndroidManifest.xml file, the error is gone.

The difference appears to be from referring to an Android system wide provided theme "@android", to a locally defined theme "@style". Using the locally defined theme works due to having defined the gradle dependency on the appcompat library `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'`, which is imported as a local theme.

For reference, the official documentation from Google for Android Developers around adding the ActionBar on Android devices 2.1+ instructs to use:  `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"`
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

Answer (score 5):

From Android Studio, different than Eclipse:

1. Open the build.gradle file for your application.
2. Include the appcompat project and add compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+" to the dependencies section, as shown in the following example:

   dependencies {
       ...
       compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
   }
3. My note: In styles.xml, remove the reference to Android as in:

   style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"

[For more details, read link](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)

Comment: Not working for me with the latest versions of the Android Studio "development suite" as of today.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the dependency responsible for that style is not being recognized.

just delete these from build.gradle if you have them:

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

then sync, then undo delete, then sync again.

Answer (score 0):

Use Theme.AppCompat.Light instead of AppCompat.Theme.Light

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate Caches/restart in the file menu always does the job for me