# Android Studio - Create new project with errors?

Tags: android, android-studio

I create a new android studio project over the wizard and choose `Empty Activity` (checked backward compatibility too). After the project is created, I got this two errors:

[image]

What is wrong? I don´t change any line code and I don´t find any solution for this.

I use the current version of android studio (checked updates a minute ago):
`Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3`

Thanks!

Comment: Clean the project and Rebuild again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to confirm these details

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Clean and Rebuild Project

Comment: Thank you. The errors are gone after adding this lines.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct imports. Try:

```
import de.kampis_elektroecke.dogsvscats.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Goto: src -> main -> res -> style.xml and add Base. to the style tag parent attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
... 
</style>
```

If that doesn't work, see this post:[Theme.AppCompat.Light resource not found in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484216/theme-appcompat-light-resource-not-found-in-android-studio)