# resource style/Theme.Base not found

Tags: android

I am getting this error in the android studio when I am trying to build android code into my device?

> error: resource style/Theme.Base (aka com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt:style/Theme.Base) not found.
>   error: failed linking references.

Comment: Are you sure that resource is present?

Comment: share your styles xml

Comment: @AM no resource is not present. Can you share me a code snippet for the same?

Answer (score 5):

Use AppTheme in your manifest file check code and see the line where i will comment

```
     <application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">  // here
```

Check style have to be like this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       ....customize Theme....
</style>
```

and Appcompat library should be updated :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

and check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26079830/7319704) also.

Comment: Yeah i have changed it as : 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
But still it is not working.
@Abhinav Gupta

Comment: I did both the changes as you suggested but still i am getting the error below:

 error: resource style/Theme.Base (aka com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt:style/Theme.Base) not found.

Actually my end goal is to build BLE terminal like application for which i have imported bluetoothLEGATT sample code into android studio.

Comment: How to remove the error as below:

ERROR: Certificate for <jcenter.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.iitk.ac.in, iitk.ac.in]

Comment: @tshivam check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45159167/7319704

Comment: Still facing the same error below @abhinav gupta:

Android resource linking failed
error: resource style/Theme.Base (aka com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt:style/Theme.Base) not found.
error: failed linking references.

Comment: @tshivam after 9pm shall we connect on teamviewer?

Comment: hi i have a question, i am sending ascii text from arduino side and receiving it in android mobile application through bluetooth low energy module. My problem is that on the android side i am getting hexadecimal equivalent symbols along with ascii text characters. i want to remove all hexa decimal symbols from the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Either change:

```
style name="AppBaseTheme"
```

to

```
style name="AppTheme"
```

in your styles.xml file. Or change:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

in your manifest application tag.

Both should be the same. Basically, your app is trying to use AppBaseTheme which doesn't exist.