# Android AppCompat cannot be resolved?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt, android-appcompat

I import my android project and it's giving errors saying anroid.support cannot be resolved? I tried importing the appcompat in the folder of the ADT sdk, but it returns an error saying unable to resolve target 'android-19'. Then, as I try to add the dependency, I have two libaries with x's and when I press add and add the v7 appcompat and press ok, it says the dependencies are mismatched. Any help?

Console:

```
[2014-07-18 20:00:32 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'
[2014-07-18 20:00:32 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'
[2014-07-18 20:00:32 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp] Versions found are:
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp] Path: C:\Users\Sruj\Documents\myswappandroid\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp]     Length: 648327
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp]     SHA-1: ded9acc6a9792b8f1afc470f0c9cd36d178914cd
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp] Path: C:\Users\Sruj\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp]     Length: 758727
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp]     SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-07-18 20:01:27 - mySwapp] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following link helps.
Right click on appcompat->properties->android->select Android 5.0->click ok.
Then clean the project.
http://blog.axxg.de/android-support-library-v7-appcompat-eclipse-einbinden/

Answer (score 0):

For all of the different folders that are having this issue, right click them, select "Android Tools", and click "Add Support Library". This should get the most recent support v4.

Comment: That didn't really fix much, I'm afraid. I get this: [2014-07-18 20:49:18 - android-support-v7-appcompat] File is Out of sync
[2014-07-18 20:49:20 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'. The code is still filled with errors saying android.support.v7 cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this error 
[android-support-v7-appcompat] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'
for the latest support api21 library you show follow the steps .Adding libraries with resources.
make sure of 6,7 steps that give this android-19 error

Click [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

or

go to libs folder Right click ->android-support-v7-appcompat.jar -> Build path ->add To path

go to libs folder Right click ->android-support-v4.jar -> Build path ->add To path

following these steps fixed my problem