# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

**Full error:**

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar'.
```

I'm trying the change the color of the action bar, i referenced to http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html.

I have tried increasing the minimum api but that dosn't help.

I have also looked at this question: [Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

But i don't know how to do that in Android Studio

```
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">0xff5a00</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

That means that you are not using AppCompat library, instead use the native ActionBar style.

**sample:**

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
```

Comment: well, the reason i posted this question was because i want to use the support librarys. Should i not use them though? If i should how do i solve this problem using the appCompat librarys? Thanks for answering, really appreciate it :)

Comment: @OscarJunker you are actually using the support library.. in your class try to import android.support.*; if it is not saying any error then you are currently using the support library

Comment: @OscarJunker so you are using support library no need to implement the theme for AppCompat

Comment: could you please explain this in more depth, i'm not sure i understand :)

Comment: @OscarJunker you said that you only need support library which by default you already have when you create a project.