# New Android apps can't find Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: java, android, eclipse, themes, android-appcompat

I've made a couple of Android apps that went really well, and no errors came up. But now, in Eclipse, whenever I try to make a new Android Project, errors come up saying

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '
 Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

Even though the exact same theme/style is in my other, perfectly working Android projects, the projects I try to start have these errors, and don't generate a R.java file. Any ideas why? And yes, I imported AppCompat, v7.

EDIT:
It shows up in 'Android' under Properties w/ a red X, when I add it again it has a green check, but if I close and reopen properties it changes to an X again. WHY!?!?!?!? I've tried cleaning, too, but it doesn't change anything. There's no R.java generated, errors in the MainActivity, somer AppCompat problem that doesn't even exists w/ my earlier projects. What's causing this?

Comment: Have you added the support library to those projects?

Comment: @azael
sdk/extras/android/support/v7/libs/appcompat or something like that, right? Yeah I added it.

Comment: Did you do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17881186/4324834?

Comment: @Azael I'm trying but there's a little red X next to the thing in the Android section. Do you know why?

Comment: The means the path to the library is incorrect, choose the right path

Comment: @Azael Never mind, I was looking at thre wrong thing. I added AppCompat, green check next to it, but that didn't fix the error.