# Eclipse android project error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have recently started learning android programming. I have set up `Eclipse IDE` for android but whenever I create a java project and click finish. It creates the project and shows the following error on the console while the **Android project wizard** does not close.

```
 Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

I also select the theme to none on the **project wizard** but that doesn't work either.

Please help!!

Comment: Please check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support

Comment: If you just started learning android you should be using `Android Studio` not eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You need to do **Next** in Eclipse:

- File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose
  "appcompat"
- Project-> properties->Android. In the section library
  "Add" and choose "appCompat"

**Note**: for more see this example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

You can start by using `Android Studio` it's more cooool :)

hope this help!

Comment: File import is not working when I paste the directory of `appcompat-v7` folder in the file import menu it shows nothing. I have already installed android studio but I want to familiarize myself with eclipse..

Comment: it didn't work either. I think, I better stick with android studio.