# Error with appcompat module

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

My problem was Ide didnt detect `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

```
<style name="mytheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Then i decide to add appcompat module to my project!

When i add **appcompat** module to my project its return this error when compile it :

```
Error:android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] ERROR: Unknown option '--output-text-symbols'
Error:android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] Android Asset Packaging Tool
```

Im using **Intelij Idea** ide and **android api 17**
and also :

```
<uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="9"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

Comment: Did you add the dependency to `{project}/build.gradle`     
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'? And added the `Android Support Library` on SDK Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minsdkVersion should be set as high as your targetsdkVersion(or atleast >= api version 11) to use the appcompat library.

If you're using intelliJ you'd want to go to project structure-->module-->Android-Gradle and put all sdkversions under properties and flavors to the most recent.

And if you'd set the dependency in build.gradle to the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Or at least that solved the problem for me.