# Android Theme.AppCompat not found - but Google instructions respected

Tags: android

I am fighting against Android and compatibility library AppCompat and I am loosing. I come here crying for help.

Since I would like to use a `NavigationDrawer` (using the code automatically generated by Android Studio) I have to start using the AppCompat library. My app does not work any more because the builder cannot find the theme AppCompat.

I followed all the steps here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

This is the gradle file "Module:app":

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "19.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.misc.application"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
 buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
      debug {
          debuggable true
      }
  }
} 

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
   compile project(':another-library-here.')
}
```

And this is the res/values/style.xml

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
  </style>

</resources>
```

The error is:

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found 
that matches the given name 
'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Since I did everything the doc says and I also removed/reinstalled the compatibility library as suggested in an answer to another StackOverflow question, I do not know what else I could try.

Could it be related to the fact that I am using API and build tools ver. 19 and the the Android Support Library 21.0.3? (I think not, but ...)

---

This is the new gradle, but building keeps failing:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.autostradetech.orchestra.negoziante"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':orchestra.autostradetech.it.')
}
```

Nothing changes if I set `minSdkVersion` to 14, 7, 8, or any other random number.

Comment: Have you tried instead of `parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` use `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: @Marcus Yes I tried changing that value with all the possibilities I could think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `android:Theme.AppCompat` just `Theme.AppCompat`. Only resources from framework have the prefix.

Also change the compile SDK version to 21. The support library version, target SDK and compile SDK versions should correspond.

Comment: Thanks. Now it finds the theme. I have only 100 other parents who went missing. I accepted this job after years of developing with iOS and I thought I would have found a similar platform: I was wrong.

Comment: Yes, read the edit please. After that do a clean build and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks: I owe you a beer. I don't know how that android: ended up there.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `21`, and change this in your Project Settings also. If you really want to use the `appcompat-v7` library, then I suppose `minSdkVersion` should be at least `14`.

**EDIT:** And it needs to be `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, not `android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Comment: As a software requirement, I need to implement an app that works on Android 4.4 - I don't think I can use API 21. Or can I?

Comment: @AntonioSesto: A `targetSdkVersion` of 21 will work on Android 4.4. The `targetSdkVersion` needs to be always 21 from now on because the new version of the `appcompat` library *must* be compiled against API 21. Projects that use this new library version also do not compile unless linked with API 21.

Comment: I modified the script according to your instructions, but the build fails. Nothing changes if I set minSdkVersion to 14.

Comment: I just realized the problem. Please see the edited answer. And by the way, you do need to set `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkversion` as 21.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

with:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support).

1. File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose
   "appcompat"
2. Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and
   choose "appCompat"

Comment: If I select File-> Import Module and I go to the location you said, the import fails because it does not find the file types it requires.

Comment: Have you downloaded the support library [using the SDK manager?](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download) @AntonioSesto

Comment: Yes, I did. I did step-by-step what Google says in the instructions (link in the question) -- I am using Android Studio.