# How to fix error in Eclipse: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Tags: android

When I create a new android app project in Eclipse, there is some note:

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout? and NOTE:
>   This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which
>   can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.

How can I fix them?

---

There is still an error:

> [2015-04-09 21:45:42 - sms] D:\work\sms\res\values\styles.xml:7:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. [2015-04-09 21:45:42 -
>   sms]  [2015-04-09 21:45:42 - sms]
>   D:\work\sms\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. [2015-04-09 21:45:42 - sms]  [2015-04-09
>   21:45:42 - sms] D:\work\sms\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. [2015-04-09 21:45:42 -
>   sms]

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Fix project properties" For that 
Right click on project name in Project Explorer -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties and then "Clean project" (Project -> Clean).

This worked for me.

Comment: @oliver: Can you show me your Style.xml code ? 
Also This can be a helpful link particularly 2nd answer  in it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support