# What is the difference between Android parent="@style/xyz" and parent="xyz"?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

What is the difference between: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20830747/761288

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Which is the preferred/correct method?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no difference apart from a bit longer text with `@style`