# Android theme "Theme.AppCompat" cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

[image]
[image]
[image]

In order to use "Theme.AppCompat" in my project I created a separate library project named "android-support-v7-appcompat" and included this.
However, the theme cannot be resolved, although I exactly followed the steps as described in [Adding libraries with resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) on Android Developers.
What went wrong?
Maybe the project cannot be resolved correctly, because if I open the dialog "Properties" on my project again and select the tab "Android" I get the following (see last picture) ...

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support) answer, I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: yes thx, it had to do with a bug in Eclipse when using different drives (see solution below), everything else was configured correctly ...

Answer (score 0):

I had problems like that a few times and for me the solution was copy the file android-support-v7-appcompat.jar or android-support-v4.jar to the libs folder of my project and then go to Java Build Path and click on Add JAR and here add the files from the libs folder.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: thx anyway, but this didn't help. The problem is not to use the libs rather than use the resources of the appcompat project.

Answer (score 0):

oh, very tricky, this problem !

This seems to be a **bug in Eclipse** when using **different drives** for the libs and the main project itself:

So, if you have the Android Support Library in your C: drive and your project in the D: drive on your computer, Eclipse won't function correctly and won't know where the Android Support Library is (green tick turns into red cross -> see my picture).
To solve this, you need to move both projects onto the same hard drive.