# appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android, ant, google-play-services, aapt

an app which I have written 2 years ago does not compile anymore for me. I used eclipse to write the code, but I try to build on the cmdline now.

The failure happens in aapt:

appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.

The full build log is at

The [full build log](http://paste.debian.net/362411/) (output of ant debug).

Can anybody tell what is going wrong?

I uploaded the [source code](http://netcup.bokomoko.de/~rd/LoMe.tgz)

Comment: possible duplicate of this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

Comment: I recovered an old laptop which still had the old Android SDK installation. With that it compiled flawless.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material

On `Eclipse` go to:

`Project -> Properties -> Android`

(Project Build Target) and select equal to your appcompat library project.

Or make sure you've added `AppCompat` in your project.

By the way, i think this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Eclipse showed to many issue, there have been changes in GooglePlayServices and LocationClient. I could not get it compiled with the new version of the Android SDK. I recovered an old laptop which build the app nicely again.

Comment: I've faced with this issue and that fixed with my answer or adding the newest version of appcompat, also make sure this is also has the same error or not:  `@style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar`.of course, i recomend you to use android studio for material design btw.