# Eclipse Android app project issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, windows-7-x64

I just downloaded all of the things for making an Android app, I usually use Python so first time I work with this.

I opened Eclipse -> File -> New -> Android Application Project. Gave name etc. After I choose `Blank activity` the name of Activity Name: `MainActivity` and Layout name: `activity_main` I press finish and this window is not closing, I just see error logs on Eclipse:

> C:\Users\windows\Desktop\ANDROID\eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64\test_prg\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.`
>
> C:\Users\windows\Desktop\ANDROID\eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64\Flafel\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.`

I searched for it on Google but I don't understand anything, Eclipse and workspace is in the same location. Both of them in the folder named ANDROID on Desktop. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: See the following link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support

Comment: @Saud I already did. There is no `android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7` in my list. There is an `Android` folder and there is only 1 file under it: Existing Android Code Into Workspace

Comment: If you're really just starting out, use Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked my own SDK for eclipse and I have a folder named android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7 . then I would suggest you download new SDK and android studio. Google has stopped giving support for eclipse for a long time.