# cannot resolve parent="Theme.appcompat" in intellij idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

i tried to use appcompat library in intellij(without gradl) by using this code

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
```

but intellij couldnt compile.what is my problem?
i am using intellij 15 and Api 15

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support

Comment: @Bajal its not same