# How to solve "Theme.AppCompat.Light" error?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to create a splash screen to my Android program. I am using C# and Xamarin in Visual studio to write my app.

I have followed a Xamarin Tutorial on how to create splash screen, when building the app, it gave me this error:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name (Theme.AppCompat.Light)

in my `Style.xml`.

Here is my `Style.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I have searched all the internet for a solution to my problem but didn't worked. Please don't consider it as duplicate cause I have seen all the answers and they didn't fixed my problem.

Comment: Please show how you declare your main activity attributes and what you have in your styles. xml nad your manifest. Also check that your styles.xml Build Action is set to AndroidResource

Comment: @YuriS I have edited my question and put my Style.xml file. Also I checked the Build Action and it was set to AndroidSource. Still have the problem

Comment: Did you install all packages with Support libraries like android-support-v7-appcompat? What is your API level of compilation is set to?

Comment: Also take a look, may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support?rq=1 Search more, there are many things you can try

Comment: I have downloaded Android Support Repository and the API level is 23. Also, this link didn't fix my problem. I am still stucking with this.. @YuriS

Comment: Can you share test project indicating the problem?