# Eclipse Android Project Not Building Correctly

Tags: eclipse, android-sdk-2.1

Recently I was attempting to make a new Android app on my windows computer with eclipse, however when creating the project an error was thrown and it wouldn't finish setup. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

**Error**

```
[2017-04-26 19:17:55 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:55 - peen]
[2017-04-26 19:17:55 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:55 - peen]
[2017-04-26 19:17:55 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:55 - peen]
[2017-04-26 19:17:56 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:56 - peen]
[2017-04-26 19:17:56 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:56 - peen]
[2017-04-26 19:17:56 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:56 - peen]
[2017-04-26 19:17:57 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:57 - peen]
[2017-04-26 19:17:57 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:57 - peen]
[2017-04-26 19:17:57 - peen] D:\developing\workspace\peen\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2017-04-26 19:17:57 - peen]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

Comment: @JohnJoe I took a look at the post, but I can't find the specified path when using the import button.

Comment: What `button` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe http://prntscr.com/f1plcq

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32267446/5156075)

Comment: I checked in my SDK manager and the package doesn't exist. I am using eclipse though. @JohnJoe

Comment: Sorry..Use Android Studio instead of Eclipse