# Android Toolbar and Tab color separation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have defined the tabs in side one of the AppCompatActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.TestActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The tool bar I set it inside activity like below

```
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Test");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

After tab attached, I see the color separation between toolbar and tab.

[image]

How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you are setting up your action bar, add this line:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

The "color separation" you're seeing is the shadow cast by the action bar on your activity's contents. The TabLayout is part of that contents, so if you don't want a shadow you should remove the action bar's elevation.

### Update

If you need to support older API versions, you will probably want to create your own `Toolbar` in xml and then call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` so that you can modify its appearance however you'd like. This xml should work for you:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

And then call this before you start calling `getSupportActionBar()`

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: yes setElevation is removing, it wont affect the versions below 21 ?

Comment: @RoshanA I updated my answer to include a strategy for solving the problem on older api versions

Comment: Then I need to create the toolbar in every activity that  needs tabs ?

Comment: Yep. You could just `<include>` it or use a `<ViewStub>` if you wanted to improve re-usability, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your TabLayout inside an AppBarLayout, I leave the following code that you can adapt to your design

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main.coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/example.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="@string/flexible_title"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="12dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingTextAppearance.Inverse"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
    />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@null"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
                style="@style/ToolBarWithNavigationBack"
        />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Toolbar Title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    ​
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
​
<!-- The top margin value equals half height of the blue box -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
/>
​
​
```

Comment: This activity is not my main activity.  I wont create the tool bar again.

Comment: Ok but I see you have a CoordinateLayout and you can add a new Toolbar to add the effect of collapsing it when the user goes down and up in the content, it's a good effect

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the theme **Theme.AppCompat** . As I know this does not have delimiter between actionbar and tabs.

Or try inserting the attribute windowContentOverlay to your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" I added like this. still I see the separation.

Comment: my app theme like this,     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
if I change to like you said I get an error.

Comment: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" Try without light. As I know the Light theme gives the devider

Comment: no still I am getting separation. what theme you are saying  ?

Comment: have you tried the code from the answer? Try it and say what error you get if you get one

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    </style> still I get the separation.

Comment: tabs should be inside toolbar ?

Comment: it's about importing the v7, check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support