# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, mobile

I'm getting 4 errors on Android Studio in my v24/values-v24.xml file, which is right here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored"/>
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media"/>
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media"/>
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media"/>
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media"/>
```

Here are the four errors:

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

Any idea how to resolve this? Does it have anything to do with my targetSDKversion being 23?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do next:

```
File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "AppCompat"

Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "AppCompat"
```

That is all!

Check answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support) by @Svyatoslav Lobach

Comment: Sorry but do you mean Import Settings? That's the only option I can find under 'File'.

Comment: That answer is for an older (2013) version of Android Studio, so I'm not able to find that specific path. There's a folder called appcompat-v7 in the 'support' folder and it has appcompat files for a bunch of different versions, from 18.0.0 to 26.0.0 (and each of those versions is a folder with a bunch of different 'appcompact' files in them). Do you know which one I'm specifically supposed to add?